# Read\Write\Navigate XML in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, xml, silverlight

I use System.Xml.XmlDocument class for most of xml operations which require read, write and navigating an xml file. Although it is a heavy weight class, it is much easier to use and fits in well for most of my apps. But XmlDocument are not available in silverlight. Is there a class in silverlight which is as easy to use as XmlDocument?

I know about using XmlReader in silverlight but it is not as flexible as XmlDocument, e.g. you cannot move back and forth in the xml, you cannot read and write in the same xml (you can only read if you are using XmlReader).

Is XDocument as usable as XmlDocument? Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Personaly, I love the XDocument class versus the XmlDocument class. Far more easyier to use (as part of the XLinq framework).

I advise you to take a look, and come back here to describe problems if you have